# Why my Image Quality is not good while sending it to server in My Android App?

Tags: android

This is my code to send Image on Server . my image is going to server but not in good quality.

```
photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
image_from_camera.setImageBitmap(photo);
if(photo != null)
{
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);

    //Here if I increase the size of quality like up to 
    //photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);
    //then i am getting BAD REQUEST ERROR i.e request exceeds size limit.
    byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    image_string_chore_detail = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr,Base64.DEFAULT);

    System.out.println(
        "IMAGE STRING IN CHORE DETAILS::  "+image_string_chore_detail);
}
```

So please help me what to do....

Answer (score 0):

> Use png-32 format for good quailty.
>
> > > change the format in photoshop and by this you will improve the quailty.

Comment: Ya i did that replace the value 100 on behalf of 50 for Quality issue but. if i use 100 value and i am sending Base64 encoded string to server in Json ......... I got error BAD REQUEST 400. and if i use 50 value its working fine so my question is:: WHERE I AM WRONG IF I USE 100 QUALITY SIZE ITS THROW ME ERROR BAD REQUEST.   need help ........thanks

Comment: can u send the image to me .i will improve the quality in jpeg

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are reducing the image quality to half the original in this line while compressing,

```
photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, stream);
```

The 50 in this line means half. Maybe u have to try it with 100 which will provide you full quality without any loss.

Comment: Ya if i am doing  photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);   its throw me Bad Request 400. from server in android.........please help me any adv solution...

Answer (score 0):

The string is too large for your server to handle. You need to change the settings in the server to allow a larger file.